# Is geofence accuracy dependent on locationManager’s accuracy or distance filter?

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, geofencing, clregion

Is geofence accuracy dependent on locationManager’s accuracy or distance filter? Or they are independent of each other because geofence is managed by the OS and uses Wifi/Cell tower info?

For example:

**locationManager**

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = 1250;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
```

**region**

```
let title = "Lorrenzillo's"
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.703026, -121.759735)
let regionRadius = 550.0


let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude,
longitude: coordinate.longitude), radius: regionRadius, identifier: title)
```

The `550` (radius) is less than `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer`...so would the geofence trigger as expected?

From what I understand the `distanceFilter` has no effect on the geofence’s accuracy.
I’m just not sure if the `desiredAccuracy` of the manager would affect geofence’s accuracy.

Comment: Absolutely, it depends on your gps' accuracy. Geo-fence is a relative value (area here) and it totally depends on the value you are comparing.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't but stackoverflow is a community. People have their own opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question makes no sense; you are comparing apples and tigers. Geofencing and your app's location manager have nothing at all to do with each other.

Geofencing using a circular region is performed for you *by the system*. Your location manager doesn't do *any* geofence-related locating. The system does not use, and knows nothing of, your app's location manager or its settings; indeed, your app will probably not even be running.

(You will, of course, need a location manager in order to have a location manager delegate so that you can receive callbacks from the system when the user crosses the geofence boundary, but your location manager is still not doing any locating related to geofencing.)

Comment: FWIW I was following [this](https://www.appcoda.com/geo-targeting-ios/) tutorial and there the author sets up the distanceFilter and desiredAccuracy. And you're saying it's completely unnecessary for geofence. It makes sense. I've already accepted it, but if you could provide a reference it would be better